# JSON response format in C

Tags: c, arrays, json

I have a task to send a JSON response to a request coming from a website in C . I am not able to format the response in the right format .

Basically this is the process : A user clicks on "StopAll" button on the website and I need to send back data of all devices back as a response that everything has been successfully done. I know how the raw data and format should look like .... But I am not able to convert it into "C"......

DATA :

Update all request:

```
{powerStates: [true, false], startStates: [false, false], temperatures: [30, 40], macAddresses: ['11', '22'], status_code: 1}
```

Code I tried :

```
if (client) {
    Serial.println ("new client");
    // An http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected ()) {
      if (client.available ()) {
        char c = client.read ();
        buffer + = c;
        Serial.write (c);

        // If you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // Character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // So you can send a reply

          if (buffer.indexOf ("true")> = 0 || buffer.indexOf ("false")> = 0) {

          // You're starting a new line

          client.println ("HTTP / 1.1 200 OK");
          client.println ("Content-Type: application / json");
          //client.println ();
          client.println ("{\" powerStates \ ": [\" true \ ", \" true \ ", \" true \ "], \" startStates \ ": [\" false \ ", \" false \ " , \ "false \"], \ "temperatures \": [\ "444 \", \ "22 \", \ "33 \"], \ "macAddresses \": [\ "11-22-33-34 \ ", \" 11-22-33-35 \ ", \" 11-22-34-37 \ "], \" status_code \ ": 1}");
          client.println ();
```

The above is the response code ..... but it does not change any data on the website . So am not sure if this response is going to the web or not .

Is there a way to find ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one simple JSON to output, you could avoid a JSON library, and just use printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Output simple fixed JSON data.
int main(int argc, char* *argv)
{
    // Simulate your data as simply as possible
    bool powerStates[2];
    bool startStates[2];
    int temperatures[2];
    int macAddresses[2];
    int status_code;


    // Set your data
    powerStates[0] = true;
    powerStates[1] = false;
    startStates[0] = false;
    startStates[1] = false;
    temperatures[0] = 30;
    temperatures[1] = 40;
    macAddresses[0] = 11;
    macAddresses[1] = 22;
    status_code = 1;


    // Output JSON very simply
    printf("{powerStates: [%s, %s], startStates: [%s, %s], temperatures: [%d, %d], macAddresses: ['%d', '%d'], status_code: %d}",
           powerStates[0]?"true":"false",
           powerStates[1]?"true":"false",
           startStates[0]?"true":"false",
           startStates[1]?"true":"false",
           temperatures[0],
           temperatures[1],
           macAddresses[0],
           macAddresses[1],
           status_code = 1);

    return 0;
}
```

If you need it in a string instead of output, just change to sprintf.

Comment: Thanks a lot . So is this sending the response to the website or is it getting a response from the website and printing it to the console? I need to send this data as a response to the request I get from the website

Comment: Per your question, this formats the response in the right format - and outputs it to the console  -- which will go back to the WWW server if your C program is operating as a CGI program.  If you are not CGI, simply change printf to sprintf and store in a buffer to output via your system's API.

Comment: Hii , I tried , the response completes but the states on the website dont change